# applying a function to lists within a list

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to apply a function to lists within a list.  The second-level lists consist of an arbitrary number of strings (which is why, in less I am missing something, the list-within-list data structure is the most appropriate).  I would like to know what the most efficient way to do this is.  Here's a simple example that accomplishes what I want with a loop:

```
#sample data
set.seed(12345)
mylist <- list()
mylist[[1]] <- list(sample(letters,3),sample(letters,4),sample(letters,5))
mylist[[2]] <- list(sample(letters,4),sample(letters,5))
mylist[[3]] <- list(sample(letters,5),sample(letters,3),sample(letters,4),sample(letters,2)

#working loop example
result <- list()
for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
  result[[i]] <- lapply(mylist[[i]],function(x,l) 0  + (l %in% x),l=letters)
}
```

Is there a simple way to turn this loop into a one-line solution?

The broader context of this is that I want to then reduce the data in `result` further, for example (in this simple case) by adding up to get the number of times each letter occurs over i, or the original dimension of `mylist`.  So the final goal is something like:

```
final.result <- lapply(result,Reduce,f='+')
```

So an alternative might be to simply apply the function to `unlist(mylist)` and then somehow restore the i information to the resulting data structure...this seems more complicated to me but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the recursive `?rapply` with argument `how='list'` to keep the list structure and then wrap `Reduce` to get your final result:

```
lapply(rapply(mylist,function(x) letters %in% x + 0, how='list'), Reduce, f='+')
```

Your function can be shortened using `letters` as pointed out by Colonel Beauvel.

Comment: `rapply(mylist,function(x) letters %in% x + 0, how='list')` is neater

Answer (score 4):

for your first result, you can do:

```
result <- lapply(mylist, function(x){lapply(x, function(y) {+(letters %in% y)})})
```

To get the final result, you can do:

```
final.result <- lapply(mylist, function(x){colSums(do.call("rbind",lapply(x, function(y) {+(letters %in% y)})))})
```

Or, using `result`:

```
lapply(result, function(x){colSums(do.call("rbind", x))})
```

Both give:

```
final.result
#[[1]]
# [1] 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 2 0 1
#
#[[2]]
# [1] 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
#
#[[3]]
# [1] 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```